# Vertical positioning of bootstrap toggles

Tags: css, html

I have a couple of bootstrap toggle buttons, as shown in the example below.

For weird reasons, the button text is always vertically aligned to the top whereas the various examples taken from the bootstrap website show button texts vertically centered.

[image]

Looking at the doc available on the website (http://www.bootstraptoggle.com), I did not find out any additional setting to put in my code :

```
    <div class="example">
        <span class="label label-primary">chk01 - Chambre 1 [A]</span>
        <input id="chk01" type="checkbox" data-onstyle="success" data-toggle="toggle" data-height="25">
    </div>
    <div class="example">
        <span class="label label-primary">chk02 - Chambre 2 [B]</span>
        <input id="chk02" type="checkbox" data-onstyle="success" data-toggle="toggle" data-height="25">
    </div>
    <div class="example">
        <span class="label label-primary">chk03 - Chambre 3 [N]</span>
        <input id="chk03" type="checkbox" data-onstyle="success" data-toggle="toggle" data-height="25">
    </div>
    <div class="example">
        <span class="label label-primary">chk04 - Salle de bains (Lavabo) [C]</span>
        <input id="chk04" type="checkbox" data-onstyle="success" data-toggle="toggle" data-height="25">
    </div>
    <div class="example">
        <span class="label label-primary">chk05 - Salle de bains (Baignoire) [D]</span>
        <input id="chk05" type="checkbox" data-onstyle="success" data-toggle="toggle" data-height="25">
    </div>
    <div class="example">
        <span class="label label-primary">chk06 - Lumi&#232;re WC [Z]</span>
        <input id="chk06" type="checkbox" data-onstyle="success" data-toggle="toggle" data-height="25">
    </div>
```

Any idea about what I have missed? I hope my question is clear enough. Many thanks for your kind help.

Comment: first noticeable difference from the docs is that the docs *wrap* the input with a label. try a label - there might be some styling in the label that affects the input; or close the span after the input.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, it did not solve my issue

Comment: i also see [http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls] that the text is always after the input. can you try it like that. also test without the label and label-primary css. if possible, create an online demo and/or direct to a live page, if available.